# ESP was not properly saved across a function call when using function pointers

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I am trying to create a program which saves the function pointer of a member function to an array. The program then takes the function pointer from that array and calls the function said pointer points to. This works as long as the member function used does not have any arguments. When I give it arguments the following error occurs in Visual Studio 2017:

> Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention.

My code is:

```
typedef uint8_t byte;

template<typename T>
class Test
{
public:
    void FuncTest(byte* data)
    {
        cout << (T)(0.0625f) << endl;
    }
};

typedef Test<float> fTest;
typedef Test<long long> lTest;

int main()
{
    byte data[1024];

    {
        void (fTest::*ffp)(byte*) = &fTest::FuncTest;
        //void (lTest::*lfp)(byte*) = &lTest::FuncTest;

        printf("%p\n", ffp);

        memcpy(&data[0], (int64*)&ffp, sizeof(int64));
    }

    {
        int64 pData;

        memcpy(&pData, &data[0], sizeof(int64));

        void(*func_pointer)(byte*) = (void(*) (byte*))(pData);

        printf("%p\n", pData);

        func_pointer(nullptr);
    }
}
```

If anyone could help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Pointers to member functions aren't like ordinary pointers to functions. Your code has some very undefined behavior.

Comment: You're going to need `std::function` and a lambda or `std::bind` to make this all work since you are using functions from different classes.

Comment: Expanding on the comment by @StoryTeller, pointer to member functions need an *object* to be called on. If you don't have an object, you can't call the function.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem "I am trying to create a program which saves the function pointer of a member function to an array" ... this is what you think is the solution, but what is the problem? Why do you think you need function pointers in the first place?

Comment: @StoryTeller and @Some programmer dude: I changed FuncTest to be static and ffp to be `void (*ffp)(byte*) = &FuncTest;` and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the storage in an array your code is essentially:

```
void (Test::*ffp)(byte*) = &fTest::FuncTest;
void* pData = (void*)ffp;
void(*func_pointer)(byte*) = (void(*) (byte*))(pData);
func_pointer(nullptr);
```

The type of `ffp` is essentially (although not exactly due to differing calling conventions) `void (fTest*, byte*)` which doesn't match the type of `func_pointer`.

The solution to this is to use `std::function` with with either `std::bind` or lambdas to convert the function signatures. e.g.:

```
std::vector<std::function<void(byte*)>> functions;
fTest test;
functions.push_back([=](byte* data){ test.FuncTest(data); });
functions.front()(nullptr);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I found my mistake. The function should have been static. That being said, I will take your answer into consideration in case I decide to use member functions in the future.